# package keyval error: compat2 undefined

Tags: errors, geometry, key-value

I am using MiKTeX 2.9, `geometry` v5.6. I am getting the following error 
package `keyval` error: `compat2 undefined.`

The LaTeX code is attached here:

```
\documentclass[phD,synopsis,a4paper]{iitmdiss}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,cite,epsfig,xcolor} % easier math formulae, align, subequation
%\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[small,it]{caption}
%\usepackage[countmax]{subfloat}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{subfigure}
%\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2.1cm,top=2.1cm,bottom=2.1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[compat2, margin=2cm]{geometry}


\title{TITLE OF THESIS}

\author{NAME}

\date{MONTH YEAR}
\department{PHYSICS}


\begin{document}

%\nocite{*}
\maketitle



% The main text will follow from this point so set the page numbering
% to arabic from here on.
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{0}
%\newpage
\section{Introduction}
kdjflsadfj kjlksjdlkf
\section{Motivation, Objective and Scope}

\section{Summary of the Research Work}

\section{Conclusions}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Bibliography.

\begin{singlespace}
\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Bibliography}

\bibitem{paper1}
Author 1 and Author 2
\newblock {\em Paper title}.
\newblock Journal\ \ {\bf Volume}, Page\ \ (Year).
\end{thebibliography}

\end{singlespace}



%%%%%%

\section{Proposed Contents of the Thesis}
The outline of the thesis is as follows:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Chapter 1 title
\item Chapter 2 title
\item ...
\end{enumerate}


%\vskip 4cm
%%%%%%
\section{Publications}
\subsection{Papers in Refereed Journals}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Title \\
    {\bf Author 1}, Author 2...\\
    {\it Journal title.}, {\bf Volume}, Page (Year)
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{Presentations in Conferences}
\begin{enumerate}
\item  Presented titled  {\em Title} at the {\bf Conference on...}  place, date..
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Whatever the `geometry` option `compat2` is for, it’s not supported anymore:

> Deleted options: `compat2` and `twosideshift`. The version 5 has no
>   longer compatibility with the previous ones. `compat2` and `twosideshift`
>   are gone for simplicity. ([`geometry` documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/geometry))

I don’t have the document class you’re using (`iitmdiss`), but if your document works without `compat2` as well, just get rid of it.

On another topic: It’s recommended to use `\textit{...}` (or simply `\emph{...}`) or `{\itshape ...}` instead of `{\it ...}`, `\textbf{...}` or `{\bfseries ...}`, etc.: [Does it matter if I use \textit or \it, \bfseries or \bf, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516/does-it-matter-if-i-use-textit-or-it-bfseries-or-bf-etc)

Also, you might get a little further with problems if you narrow down the issue more (in this case, singling out `compat2`). There’s some advice on that in [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). I contributed some hints there, too.

Answer (score 4):

Please open the file `iitmdiss.cls` and comment the `compat2` in the line number 74 as shown below.

```
\RequirePackage[% compat2,
a4paper,left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in,
                nohead]{geometry}[2002/07/08]
```

now it is running without any error.

Comment: In my opinion, this has been covered in [doncherry's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131121/5764).

Comment: if i comment compat2, it shows Package hyperref Error: Wrong DVI mode driver option `hypertex', because pdfTeX or LuaTeX is running in PDF mode.

Comment: @KBM if you make the option from `\usepackage[hypertex]{hyperref}`  to   `\usepackage{hyperref}`  it works without errors. Don't understand why we require hypertex.